# Как использовать выравнивание текста justify?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Я читал, что для использования выражения justify, необходимо подключить библиотеку.

Но я не знаю, где ее искать, в какую папку ее загружать, как подключать и как использовать.

Comment: Не очень понятна суть вашей проблемы, что *конкретно* вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы выровнять текст «[по ширине](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)» (англ. [full justification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment)), используйте атрибут `justificationMode` у виджета `TextView`:

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
    tools:targetApi="26" />
```

Эта опция доступна только на Андроид 8 и выше (API 26+), поэтому на старых версиях Андроид такое выравнивание работать не будет.